# CentOS 6 installation crashes when trying to boot media from BIOS set to UEFI mode

Tags: centos, gpt, uefi

I'm trying to install CentOS 6 on Dell R410 server. As I need a GPT large disk support, I set the BIOS to UEFI configuration. The problem is that I'm getting crashes once the server tries to boot from the media.

Any idea what I can do to continue with the installation?

Thanks!

Comment: For all we know, the crashes could be because you haven't seated an expansion card properly in its slot, and are nothing to do with either firmware or partitioning scheme.  [Are you going to give us proper information (including **the actual error messages, lights, and sounds**) about what your computer is doing?](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)  Or do you want guesswork answers based upon nothing?